# Using heroku pg:info to pull stats on a database not within an application

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Using the heroku toolbelt a person can run the following command and receive some stats about the postgres database connected to the application:

```
pg:info
```

if you are not within an application directory you will recieve the following error:

"No app specified."

but if you specify an app, then you will only be able to pull stats on the databases that where created an connected to an application. But, Heroku Postgres lets you create databases that are not connected to a specific application.

How do you use pg:info with a databases that is outside a heroku application?

There is some information in the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli) about how to use the pg:info command, but they don't mention how to use it with a standalone database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `pg:info` with Standalone Heroku Postgres databases at this time.

Comment: Do you know if this is something they are thinking about adding in the future?